# Remove city from team name

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have these variables:

```
$cities = [
    'New York City',
    'Arizona State',
    'Arkansas State'
];

$teams = [
    'New York Mets',
    'New York Yankees',
    'Arizona State Sun Devils',
    'Arkansas State Red Wolves'
];
```

How can I format the `$teams` array into the following:

```
$teams = [
    'Mets',
    'Yankees',
    'Sun Devils',
    'Red Wolves'
];
```

Thanks!

Comment: Are you able to change `New York City` to `New York`? Or add `New York` as a separate one?

Answer (score 1):

there are a dozen options, here is one, wont work if you have a any word in the city list that matches any word in the team list you want to keep. But will work for the data provided.

```
<?php
$cities = [
    'New York City',
    'Arizona State',
    'Arkansas State'
];

$teams = [
    'New York Mets',
    'New York Yankees',
    'Arizona State Sun Devils',
    'Arkansas State Red Wolves'
];

$r=implode($cities,'|');//join the cities
$r=str_replace(' ','|',$r);//separate each word with | for the regular expression

$out=preg_replace('#'.$r.'#','',$teams); // regular expression replace
```

Answer (score 0):

use the function str_replace. example:

```
<?php
$teams = [
    'New York Mets',
    'New York Yankees'
];
$out = str_replace('New York', '', $teams);
print_r($out); // Output: Array ( [0] => Mets [1] => Yankees )
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, but my variable is `New York City`, not `New York`.

Answer (score 0):

`str_replace()` can do the work for you, as it accepts arrays as parameters too. However, you'll run into an issue with `New York City`. If you're not able to either rename it to `New York`, or add `New York` as a separate element, you need to remove that first (with the `str_replace()`-line after the `$city` declaration), before you supply the `$city` to the `str_replace()` where you replace out the cities with empty strings.

```
$cities = [
    'New York City',
    'Arizona State',
    'Arkansas State'
];
$cities = str_replace("City", "", $cities);

$teams = [
    'New York Mets',
    'New York Yankees',
    'Arizona State Sun Devils',
    'Arkansas State Red Wolves'
];

// Replace cities in $cities to an empty string in the $teams array
$teams = str_replace($cities, "", $teams);
$teams = array_map("trim", $teams); // Trim away the excessive spaces
print_r($teams);
```

Output:

```
Array (
    [0] => Mets
    [1] => Yankees
    [2] => Sun Devils
    [3] => Red Wolves
)
```

- [Live demo](https://3v4l.org/0tSmZ)
- [PHP.net on `str_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)